# What's the advantage of splitting a CLI tool into multiple executables

Tags: architecture, binary, executable

I'm trying to figure out the reasoning behind splitting a CLI tool (and potentially other programs) into multiple executables.

For example [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and [Cargo](http://crates.io) both follow this approach where there is one executable (git or cargo) that basically just parses the given arguments (e.g. `init` or `update` so the call is `git init` or `cargo update`) and then calls another executable.

So basically all commands of Git or Cargo are single executables that get called through a facade.

I'm trying to wrap my head around this architecture to better understand it's benefits.

Obviously it's a way to achieve modularity not only at a source code level but also at the level of distribution.

But even that could be achieved by just throwing libraries (instead of executables) in a directory and load all of them through the main executable. I've built plugin architectures like that before with .NET.

But that's not what Git or Cargo do. As far as I understand they make sub commands real executables to be called as a process with arguments. Isn't that way more expensive than the library approach? I wonder what's the benefit of it?

I'm trying to figure out if this approach is only feasible for CLI tools but not for performance critical stuff. Like for instance for Git there is also [lib2git](https://libgit2.github.com) which seems to be a reimplementation of Git as a library.

I was wondering if the mass-of-executables approach has advantages when it comes to writing bindings for other languages. But then if we have just one executable and load subcommands from a directory as libraries it should be equally simple to write bindings from other languages through calling the main executable.

The only downside of the one-executable-plus-multiple-sublibraries approach that I see may be startup time if it has to load all sub libraries at startup.

Can somebody with a better understanding of the topic shed some light for me please?

Answer (score 2):

The performance impact between the two approaches is of no concern when developing an interactive CLI application. The bottleneck is always going to be the user typing in a command, by several orders of magnitude.

The fact that the tool suite is named "Git" or "Cargo" does not mean it is one tool. It is a large system composed of many individual tools, each of which performs a different, atomic action on the data set represented by the file system.

The library approach is reasonable if the expectation is that each component is part of one big application. That is not the case here. This is a collection of tools, and even someone who needs every tool doesn't want to have to write a host application to utilize a library's API every time they want to call a function. You might suggest there be one parent EXE included with the library called "Git.exe" which takes parameters and utilizes the libraries (which is essentially what we already have, except that you're now forcing the consumer to a] use the host executable redirection or b] write a whole new application), but now you need to dynamically load and unload a boatload of libraries every time this thing is executed. Wouldn't it be great if you could call only the one whose functionality you need explicitly when you need it?

With the modularity introduced by the collection of atomic executables, it becomes very easy to maintain a separation of concerns, document the exact input/output of each command, and provide a scripting interface to the suite that requires writing no extra code: just call the executable you need.

Would it be more performant to write an application which references a subset of the collection of proposed .DLLs and compiles into a single .EXE every time you wanted to run multiple commands on an e.g. Git repository? Absolutely. Would the performance gain be worth the time and effort of doing this over that of whipping up a Bash script that calls four .EXEs back-to-back passing some options as arguments? Almost never.

Surely there are other reasons I've not thought to address, and I would be very interested in reading any additional information you find regarding this. Hopefully I've given you something to build a query on.

Comment: Ok, but it then means I wouldn't apply this pattern to split a REST API in multiple executables because there the performance implications may show, right?

Comment: What technologies are driving the back end of your REST application? Generally when I think of REST I'm thinking of an interpreted language (e.g. PHP), not a compiled language. In the case of PHP you achieve modularity by logically separating code into multiple PHP files. Even with a compiled language, RESTful actions are generally atomic so I'm not sure what you're considering when you suggest performance implications. Perhaps you could elaborate on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, and the technologies in play.